# When using INSERT OR REPLACE INTO in SQL is there any way to tell if a record was inserted as new or replaced in SQL for AS3?

Tags: sql, actionscript-3

I've wanting to know if a record is updated vs replaced so that I can display a list of duplicate records to the user. Is this possible using something like totalChanges?

Thank you

Comment: Well, first do query by table's PK with the data being inserted, whether some data already exists. And please fix tags by adding SQL server version, as some dialects work differently with such a statement. "Actionscript-3" is currently total off topic tag ere.

Comment: Thank you, Vesper. So for each record I'm inserting, I first need to do a look up to see if that record exists first? Why is Actionscript-3 off topic here, please?